# Responsive Hexagon Grid with shadow

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have seen many available resources regarding a responsive hexagon grid but none of those solve my problem. All grids that I found so far have the shape as below

[image: This is I found in many article or tutorial]

But I want the hexagon to have this shape:

[image: This shape I want in gride]

I have tried and have achieved the desired result but the problem is that is cannot achieve via responsive layout. And also I haven't been able to apply a shadow. How can I do this?

```css
li.hex-row {
  margin-top: -100px;
}
li.hex-row:nth-child(2n) .hexagon {
  transform: translateX(50%) rotate(120deg);
}
ul#hexagonContainer {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.hexagon {
  width: 400px;
  background: transparent;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
li.hex-row {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.hexagon .hex-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hexagon .hex-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  visibility: visible;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #310073;
}
.hexagon .hex-img:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_flwr.gif);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.hex-img.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul id="hexagonContainer">
    <!-- First row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img body-care">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Second row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Third row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Fourth row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Fifth row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Sixth row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Seventh row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it responsive just changing the dimensions to vw.

About the shadow, in modern browsers it can be done with a filter drop-shadow:

```css
li.hex-row {
  margin-top: -10vw;
}
li.hex-row:nth-child(2n) .hexagon {
  transform: translateX(50%) rotate(120deg);
}
ul#hexagonContainer {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10vw;
}
.hexagon {
  width: 18vw;
  background: transparent;
  height: 9vw;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 7vw;
  position: relative;
}
li.hex-row {
  white-space: nowrap;
  filter: drop-shadow(0.5vw 2vw 0.5vw black);
}
.hexagon .hex-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.hexagon .hex-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  visibility: visible;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #310073;
}
.hexagon .hex-img:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_flwr.gif);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.hex-img.hide {
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul id="hexagonContainer">
    <!-- First row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img body-care">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Second row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Third row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Fourth row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Fifth row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Sixth row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Seventh row. -->
    <li class="hex-row">
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hexagon">
        <div class="hex-inner">
          <div class="hex-img hide">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your response sir but to be hones i achieved this result before your response but i used % measurement for hex and instead using css background-image i pur img element in side .hex-img div

Comment: Happy that it (somehow) helped. Didn't the height of .hexagon give you problems when set to a percentage ?

Comment: you can have a look here in this link usdigitalpunch.com/xfit/hexagon.html